# Função TimeStamp Android

Tags: android

Bom dia Prezados , estou  com um problema , estou utilizando a função :
porém em algumas versões do Android ele está alterando o horário aumentando uma hora a mais,alguém já passou por isso?

```
  Timestamp stampDetalhe = new Timestamp(mAtendimento.getAtp_previsao_atendimento())
```

Comment: Não seria devido ao horário de verão?

Comment: Acontece que na cidade que estou não tem horário de verão